# Can the bing spell check api via integration with LUIS.AI be used with the dispatch pattern for QnA knowledge based questions?

Tags: botframework, spell-checking, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

From what I am understanding the bing spellcheck api via azure can be integrated with LUIS queries but not qna queries on their own.  However, when you use the dispatch multi-model pattern with a parent LUIS app and child apps the overall query or top level query coming from luis can run the bing spellcheck api.

Is this the suggested method for assuring some spellchecking is applied to a qna knowledge base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Dispatch Bot. When you get the results back from the recognizer, there will be an alteredText value if spell check made a correction. What you're wanting to do is replace the original text with this new value.

```js
const recognizerResult = await this.dispatchRecognizer.recognize(context);
if (recognizerResult.alteredText) {
    context.activity.text = recognizerResult.alteredText;
}

<code to select intent>

var processResult = await this.qnaDialog.processAsync(userDialog.qnaState, context.activity)
```

QnA Maker should now receive the query with the altered text. I don't have this implementation exactly but I had to do something similar where I modified context.activity.text and removed  or @ mentions from Teams, which were affecting intent identification and QnA  answers.

Comment: thanks I think the portal with chrome and entering your key is broken.  I see now direct api requests work nicely!  thanks your answers are really good

Answer (score 0):

As billoverton mentioned, if you integrate Bing Spell Check with LUIS then you can access the spellchecked utterance in the `alteredQuery` property of the LUIS results. If you don't have a LUIS model that you're passing utterances through before they reach QnA Maker, you can always call the Bing Spell Check API directly with [HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-spell-check-api-v7-reference) or using an [Azure SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-spell-check/).

[image: Bing Spell Check SDKs]

Once you have the spellchecked utterance, you can pass it along to QnA Maker through a QnA dialog by modifying the turn context's activity like billoverton suggested, or again you can call the API directly. There's plenty of information in the [QnA Maker documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/) about generating answers with the REST API or an SDK.

[image]

Comment: Kyle, is there a way to get the full utterance back when calling Bing directly? If I pass something like "I want to look up my odrer" I get back the following result:
`{
   "_type": "SpellCheck",
   "flaggedTokens": [   {
      "offset": 21,
      "token": "odrer",
      "type": "UnknownToken",
      "suggestions": [      {
         "suggestion": "order",
         "score": 0.8853940629413616
      }]
   }]
}`
I'm sure I could deal with that if I wanted to, but much more difficult than accessing the alternateQuery/alternateText attributes.

Comment: @billoverton - Unfortunately I don't see a builtin way to automatically apply the spelling suggestions using the Bing Spell Check API or its corresponding SDK